# Edit website to be responsive based on display size

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I work on a school project that has a [website](https://aqpi.se/). The website is made by other graduated students and I have almost no HTML or CSS knowledge.
I want the website to be more mobile friendly, meaning that every frame and object gets resized according to what display size you have. Now there is text outside the display, iframes being too big, e.t.c. I have tried to fix this for hours by searching online without any major results.

The thing I've discovered is that changing from `overflow-x: auto` to `overflow-x: hidden` (in a CSS file) can help to remove overflow/bleed.

If you have any tips on how I can improve [this page](https://aqpi.se/karta.html) it would be strongly appreciated. Feel free to inspect the code using browser tools (CTRL+SHIFT+I).

- How do I resize iframes, text, images, e.t.c. according to the width and height of the display?
- Why is the footer text outside of the screen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You may be inexperienced, but we do require you to define your own objectives and make demonstrable attempt at solving the problem(s) involved in that. We won't write the code *for* you, but if you have problems with your code, your attempts, we'll be happy to help. Please, take the [tour], and read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidance.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

read this, you can also use bootstrap grid to make things easier

Answer (score 0):

For skips the most of overlaps that could occur in the page, try to use the configuation below:

```
html, body {
 // reset the browser config
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

* {
 box-sizing: border-box; // padding and border will not be added to width and height calc
}

img {
 max-width: 100%; // protect from images be more large than the container
}

// https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp
```

box-sizing: border-box; will help you in mostly cases, but in some cases, after you inspect the element with overlap width, will can use the calc() to fix it, like:

```
element {
 width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

In you case at https://aqpi.se/karta.html the problem is you setting a fixed width on the iframe element.

- [With overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAeZp.jpg)
- [Without overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L97V8.jpg)

Responsive web sites are created with media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp.